# Compiler is always disabled

Tags: magento-1.8, compiler

I have successfully run the compilation process, but when trying to enable the compilation mode, either through admin panel or through command line, I get no errors, but the state remains always **disabled**.

The folder `includes` has permissions 0775, and the file `includes/config.php` has 0777, so I don't think it's a permission issue.

Here is a typical sequence in putty:

```
myuser@serv01 [~]# php -cli public_html/shell/compiler.php disable
Content-type: text/html

Compiler include path disabled
myuser@serv01 [~]# php -cli public_html/shell/compiler.php enable
Content-type: text/html

Compiler include path enabled
myuser@serv01 [~]# php -cli public_html/shell/compiler.php state
Content-type: text/html

Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Compiled
Collected Files Count:    7605
Compiled Scopes Count:    4
```

### UPDATE

Even changing the working directory didn't help:

```
myuser@serv01 [~]# cd public_html/shell
myuser@serv01 [~/public_html/shell]# php -cli compiler.php enable
```

etc...

### UPDATE 2

The file `includes/config.php` is always empty, but the folder `includes/src` is updated / recreated during compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've lost your valid `config.php` file. The admin essentially comments out a line in that file to disable the use of the compiler (unless things have changed). Try pulling a clean `includes/config.php` from a clean Magento code base and then try enabling it again.

Comment: Thanks, I think you've got the point. As soon as I test it, I'll accept the answer or update the question!

Answer (score 0):

Default contents of `config.php` file:

```
<?php
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname   (__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```