# Magento in Compilation Process

Tags: magento-1.9

unfortunately i did the "Run Compilation Process" function after the installation an extension when "Enable status" in magento.. now am getting fatal error in my site. how can i revert my old datas ? please give a suggentsion

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options to disable compilation.

The best option if you do have command line access is to run the following command from the Magento root directory:

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
```

This will both disable compilation and clear compiled files (actually `clear` should do both but run `disable` beforehand anyway).

If you don't have command line access open the file `includes/config.php` and comment both lines which will give you:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

I have found that sometimes this is not a complete solution so also delete any directories beneath includes as this is where the compiled files are generated.

FYI the performance benefit of compilation is actually extremely minimal in all but pretty old versions of Magento - so unless you have good reason to it's probably not even worth having it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `index.php` and search for `compilerConfig` you'll see where the include is defined to enable and load the combined classes.

You can either comment out the include statement if you want a quick fix, or simply remove the config file defined.

The latter is the best approach, there's nothing to worry about as this file is rebuilt each time you recompile.

Comment: Hi Sonassi, i have did commented that regardings code      $compilerConfig = 'includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}              Site is loading But my some content are missing and having fatal error in product list page.                        how can i solve it ???

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happened to your datas
**Disable the compiler** and **delete var/cache**. It will work now.

Comment: Hi Rapid, i have deleted all files under var/cache folder but no luck i cant able to get full datas. that is there is missing some content in my site and have getting fatal error on product list page..

Comment: Hey, user3815026 Can u send screenshot for product listing page? pls. So I can help you better.

Comment: Hi rapid, i got solutions for this issue. thanks for rply.. now i cant able to change the complier status as enabled in admin panel. its always in disable. how can i do this ?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/compiler-is-always-disabled Check this link. This guy knows what u needs to do.