# unable to disable Compiler in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, compiler

Okay, it's a long story, so sit tight.

First, I cannot disable compiler for some reason.  I click `disable` and it refreshes, saying `Enabled` still.  So I used the command line and disabled it, and got the return prompt of

```
php compiler.php -- state
Compiler Status:          Disabled
```

But, if I refresh the back-end, it still reads as `Enabled`

None of my changes are taking effect due to this, and I am at a loss as to where to go from here

I have even tried recompiling from the command line, it says it runs, but same issue, my changes don't actually show in the front-end of the site

```
Compiler Status:          Enabled
Compilation State:        Compiled
Collected Files Count:    7416
Compiled Scopes Count:    4
```

If I attempt to recompile from the back-end, it locks up the site and both front and back ends are unable to be accessed

**--Edit--**

People have claimed this is a duplicate of the "compiler always disabled" thread found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/compiler-is-always-disabled), but my `config` file does not seem to be the issue

contents of `/includes/config.php` here:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Even with the 2 lines commented out, compiler still stays `Enabled`, and disabling it just adds another hash to the line for `compiler_include_path` (I had 3 hashes before deleting them and trying again.), and if there aren't lines commented, it will properly add a hash to the line in question, but still stay `Enabled`. So again, the problem does not seem to be with Magento updating this line of code.

**--Edit 2--**

Came in today and saw that the compiler was disabled, unsure why, not upset about it, but it came with an error in the code I was updating, and now the changes in the code won't take... it is like the server is taking a few days to respond to file changes for some reason

Comment: go to `includes/config.php` and comment both lines: `define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');` AND `define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');`

Comment: As stated in edit above, I have tried commenting and uncommenting the specified lines with no luck

Comment: compiler disabled, afraid to re enable it to test it, see edit 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I found my problem

APC Cache was enabled on the server, preventing files from updating immediately, hopefully this helps someone